# Como manejar peticiones HTTP demasiado grandes

Tags: javascript, http-get, requests, google-chart-api

Tengo un proyecto de React en el cual hay una sección de gráficos de datos que provienen de unos sensores. Los datos se actualizan cada 30 segundos, por lo que en un día se generan 2800 registros aproximadamente.

El problema es que los gráficos tienen un filtro de fecha, en el cuál puedes elegir un rango de fechas, un mes por ejemplo. Por lo tanto, la respuesta a esa petición es un JSON con mas de 80000 objetos. Una respuesta muy grande y que por ende, tarda demasiado en procesarse: alrededor de 40 segundos (dependiendo del ancho de banda).

¿Cómo puedo manejar ese tipo de peticiones para que sean lo mas rápido posible?

Comment: Usar peticiones AJAX no es conveniente para este caso, debido a que lo único que hacen es saturar el servidor y hacer que eventualmente se ponga lento o se caiga. Puedes probar con WebSockets.

Comment: ¿Como sería con WebSockets? Si tines enlaces de ejemplos similares, documentación o videos te agradeceria que me los compartieras.

Comment: Puedes revisar el concepto en el siguiente [enlace](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), si quieres pasar a algo práctico puedes empezar con [socket.io](https://socket.io) que corre con [tag:nodejs]

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer ese tipo de filtros, se recomienda que lo haga el motor de base de datos y no el frontend, las consultas que comenta por fecha, se deben hacer con SQL y quizás usando LIMIT también y el front sólo debe mostrar resultados, mas no hacer el ejercicio de filtro. Si los resultados necesitan otro tipo de calculos, el motor de DB lo debe hacer con un STORE PROCEDURE.  Sé que varias librerías o componentes vienen con buscadores integrados, pero son buenos para volúmenes pequeños. También lo que comenta Rodrigo Ramírez, websockets.

Comment: Si, de hecho los filtros se estan procesando así: el front solo genera los gráficos. No puede haber un limite porque se require que esten presentes todos los datos de un dia o una semana por ejemplo,  lo que serían 2800 o cerca de 20000 registros, respectivamente.